# UINavigationBar was disappeared in iOS8 and the earlier version

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uinavigationbar

The first `ViewController` is managed by a `NavigationController`, and it has a `UIWebView`. The `WebView` modules has click events to push a `ViewController` in the `NavigationController`.

---

But now, the `ViewController` which is init by code is normal, and which is `init` by `storyboard` is abnormal, the `navigation bar` was disappeared. It only occurs in iOS8 and earlier Version.

---

PS: The Init Code is like this:

Code:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Storyboard:

```
ViewController *vc = [ViewController defaultViewControllerWithStoryboard:@"StoryboardName"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

---

Thank You.

Comment: so do you think all assume your code and how did you push a viewcontroller :P

Answer (score 0):

[image: Give StoryBoard Identifier]

```
MainViewController* presentController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardidentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:presentController animated:YES];
```

if its not working try this Normally yourStoryBoardName is Main:

```
 UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
MainViewController* presentController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:presentController animated:YES];
```

Comment: The method I have tried, the result is the same as the method which is used defaultViewControllerWithStoryboard to init.